# SQL query - get parent index from level and child index

Tags: t-sql, ado

I have dataset with two columns: index and level.

Level is number indicating level in hierarchy of nested parent child records.

The records are in order of hierarchy and index is just the line number of record.

The rule is that any record's parent record has level = child level - 1.

My challenge is to identify the parent's index based on this rule.

For each record, I need to SQL query that will get the record's parent index.

The SQL query will be a self join, and get the max index value where the self join index < child.index and the self join level = child.level

I need help to figure out how to write this SQL.

I can use MS Access or use SQL in VBA to perform this query.

This is a visual representation of the data set.

[image]

This is sample data and expected result .. want to get parent index .. parent level is child level - 1.

```
Index,Level Number,Parent Level,Parent Index
1,1,1,1
2,2,1,1
4,4,3,3
9,9,8,8
3,3,2,2
5,5,4,4
8,8,7,7
6,6,5,5
7,7,6,6
10,10,9,9
11,11,10,10
12,12,11,11
13,13,12,12
14,14,13,13
15,14,13,13
16,14,13,13
17,14,13,13
18,14,13,13
19,14,13,13
20,14,13,13
21,13,12,12
22,13,12,12
23,13,12,12
24,14,13,23
25,14,13,23
26,14,13,23
27,11,10,10
28,9,8,8
29,9,8,8
30,9,8,8
31,9,8,8
32,9,8,8
33,9,8,8
34,9,8,8
35,8,7,7
36,9,8,35
37,10,9,36
38,11,10,37
39,11,10,37
40,12,11,39
41,12,11,39
42,13,12,41
43,13,12,41
44,13,12,41
45,11,10,37
46,12,11,45
47,13,12,46
48,14,13,47
49,14,13,47
50,14,13,47
51,14,13,47
52,14,13,47
53,14,13,47
54,14,13,47
55,13,12,46
56,13,12,46
57,13,12,46
58,9,8,35
59,9,8,35
60,9,8,35
61,9,8,35
62,8,7,7
63,8,7,7
64,8,7,7
65,8,7,7
66,8,7,7
67,8,7,7
68,8,7,7
```

Edited to add:
I tried to do this in Excel Power Query, and found an answer, but it takes forever to run so need to find SQL VBA/ADO solution. But here is Power Query solution to help give ideas about how to do it SQL.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle3"]}[Content],
    ParentIndex = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ParentIndex", each let Index=[Index], LN=[Level Number] in List.Max(Table.SelectRows(Source, each _[Index] < Index and _[Level Number]=LN-1)[Index])),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(ParentIndex,{"ParentIndex"},ParentIndex,{"Index"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "NewColumn", {"Level Number"}, {"Level Number.1"})
in
    #"Expanded NewColumn"
```

This Power Query solution finds Max index where each row index < all index and level = level -1

Comment: some sample along with expected result would help

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: please don't include data as image. We would have to re-type it... Please add your data a copy'n'pasteable text. Best would be a test scenario with a `CREATE TABLE` and some `INSERT INTO` statements. You'd get much more good answers...

Comment: Added some data and expected results as csv

Comment: This is tagged with sql-server and ms-access. Further more you write *or SQL in VBA* ... Is your VBA Code speking with a SQL Server? Which one is correct? And please state the Version!

Comment: Fair points. I have clarified tags. Have 'TSQL' and 'ADO'. If I execute the SQL it will be using ADO in VBA or I may run it in MS Access if the TSQL received can be modified for Access. No SQL Server is involved (should have just specified TSQL).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (val INT)
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),
    (14),(14),(14),(14),(14),(14),(14),(13),(13),(13),(14),(14),(14),(11)

SELECT REPLICATE(' ', val) + CAST(val AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM @t
```

Output

```
-----------------------------
 1
  2
   3
    4
     5
      6
       7
        8
         9
          10
           11
            12
             13
              14
              14
              14
              14
              14
              14
              14
             13
             13
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639349/sql-query-get-parent-index-from-level-and-child-index
declare @table table
(idx int, level int)

insert into @table
(idx,level)
values
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(4,4),
(5,5),
(6,6),
(7,7),
(8,8),
(9,9),
(10,10),
(11,11),
(12,12),
(13,13),
(14,14),
(15,14),
(16,14),
(17,14),
(18,14),
(19,14),
(20,14),
(21,14),
(22,13),
(23,13),
(24,13),
(25,14),
(26,14),
(27,14),
(28,11),
(29,9),
(30,8)

select  v.idx,v.level,v.parentlevel,u.idx parentidx
from
(
select s.* from                             --Find the first idx,level 
(
select  t.*,  t.level - 1 as parentlevel,
        row_number() over (partition by level order by idx,level) rownum
from    @table t
) s
where rownum = 1
) u
join                                        --join to every occurance of 
(select t2.*, t2.level - 1 parentlevel,
        1 as  rownum
from    @table t2
) v
on (v.parentlevel = u.level and v.rownum = u.rownum) 
union                                       --and put 1 back
select  w.idx,w.level,w.level,w.idx
from    @table w
where   w.idx = 1
order by v.idx
```

Comment: I did ask for TSQL so got what I asked for. It does work fine on SQL Server but just discovered TSQL windowing functions eg over partition are not available using Jet/ACE SQL in a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36674269/excel-vba-ado-sql-syntax-error-in-from-clause) Are you interested in modifying SQL there for Jet/ACE SQL?

Comment: Just took away answer check. Took closer look. This didn't get desired result.  These SQL results were correct up to Index 24. Index 24 parent index should have been 23 not 13. The grouping is looking too far up the hierarchy for min value.

Comment: The sample data for Index 24 is 24,13 should this be 24,24?

Comment: Sample data should be 24,14